# When a Sorcerer with the Maestro Bloodline casts verbal+somatic spells, are they affected by Bloodline Arcana?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer

The Sorcerer's [Maestro Bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/maestro-bloodline) has the following feature, *Bloodline Arcana:*

> Whenever you **cast a spell with a verbal component and no somatic or material component**, you treat your caster level as if it were one higher.

At level 20, it gains the *Grand Maestro* feature:

> At 20th level, the power of pure magic music flows through you. **You cast any spell with a verbal component as if it had the Still Spell metamagic feat applied to it**, with no increase to the casting time or spell slot required to cast it. You gain immunity to sonic damage and language-dependent spells.

If I were to cast a spell with only a verbal and somatic component, would my bloodline power activate making it 1 level higher, considering I did not need to perform any somatic gestures because of the Grand Maestro Ability?

Or is this not the case, because the somatic portion is still in the spell requirements regardless?

Comment: I've edited your question heavily for clarity, and attempted to dismantle the paragraph-question at the end into something clearer. Please check to make sure I've preserved your intent, and that the question still asks what you want to ask.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**.

You do a pretty good deconstruction of the issue in your question, and you are correct.  Since your bloodline arcana says that it triggers whenever you cast a spell with only a verbal component, and casting a Silent spell will get rid of the only other component, then your bloodline arcana triggers.  The arcana is interested in what components your spell has when you cast it, not what components it has on the page.

Also, from a design intent point of view (which is admittedly weaker), it doesn't make a lot of sense to include both of these features in the same bloodline without explaining how they work together, unless they work together seamlessly.

Comment: Thank you, whenever I read something I tend to read it in a favorable way for my intention and not always as intended by the designer. One thing I just noticed though is it doesn't mention focused items. I would assume that a focused item is still considered a material component for RAI, but not sure about RAW.

Comment: Nope!  Foci are foci.  The line says that the spell can't have somatic or material components, but it doesn't say that the spell can't have a focus, so you can cast spells that require foci at +1 caster level all day long.